# Inverse relationship of deposit volume to deposit rate and exchange rate of deposit currency

Tags: econometrics, interest-rate

I have data on short-term (2 months) deposits, which show an inverse relationship between the volume of deposit replenishment to the deposit rate and the exchange rate of the deposit currency. We can assume that the currency has relatively high inflation (10+% per year), the national economy is largely dependent on imports.

I can not fully understand the reasoning behind the inverse relationship. At the moment there is only one thought: when the currency rate rises, its purchasing power for foreign goods increases, this causes the desire of depositors to invest less and buy more foreign goods.

Please tell me what could be the reasoning behind this dependence?

The graph shows the dependence of the volume of deposit replenishment depending on the change of rates from the moment of opening a deposit:

[image]